# Insert multiple columns with multiple values using stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, csv

We are passing 4 parameters to a stored procedure

```
@PageID,
@CompanyID,
@URL, 
@URLCode,
```

All these parameters contains comma-separated values

Example:

```
 @PageID contains ("1,2,3,4,5,6,7")
 @CompanyID contains ("10,20,30,40,50,60,70") 
 @URL contains ("u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7")
 @URLCode contains ("c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7")
```

In database I have one table as mentioned below:

Table name : `UrlMapping`

Columns:

```
MappingID (PK), 
PageID, 
CompanyID,
URL,
UrlCode
```

Can you suggest how can insert these multiple comma separated values in `UrlMapping` table.

Answer (score 2):

It's a two step process.

Split the strings into a set of temporary tables:
[T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco?lq=1)

Join the tables back together based on a row numbering and insert into the database:

```
INSERT INTO UrlMapping 
(PageID, CompanyID)
FROM
SELECT PageID, CompanyID
(
    SELECT id AS PageID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as PageRowNum
    FROM
    @SplitPageID
) AS SplitPageID
INNER JOIN  
(
    select id AS CompanyID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as CompanyRowNum
    FROM
    @SplitCompanyID
) AS SplitCompanyID
ON
SplitPageID.PageRowNum = SplitCompanyID.CompanyRowNum
```

This is a representative query, you will need to implement the splitting, insert into in the Split temporary tables, and expand the joins to cover all columns.